# How do I count the number of users in my quiz bot?

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

I am using bot framework where I proactively start a quiz game every 24 hours. The code for this looks like

```
bot.beginDialog(user.address, '/runChallenge', args, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        // error ocurred while starting new conversation. Channel not supported?
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error), user.address)
        bot.send(new builder.Message()
            .text("The rat nibbled the wires before we could start the game for you. Sorry about that :(")
            .address(user.address));
    }
})
```

A couple of questions

1. How do i count the number of players in the game?
2. I could make a global variable called players inside my bot.js file
   and increment it by 1 each time the bot.dialog('/quiz') is called
   inside its 1st waterfall step. Given the file is included once at
   the beginning, once I increment it, I guess i ll have to reset it
   back to 0 somewhere.
3. Or I could use a local variable inside the cron job function which
       can pass another parameter called playersCount as args to the dialog
       where it will be a local variable but I am not sure if this is the
       right approach
4. Everytime, a person answers incorrectly, they are out of the
   challenge. I would like to count how many people answered
   incorrectly. What would be a good way to go about this?
5. I would also like to declare the results of the quiz after say
   everyone is done with it, The maximum time taken by anyone and
   everyone is 15 mins for the round. I am planning to use a setTimeout
   after 15 mins of initiating the game since I already use a CronJob
   every 23 hours to trigger the quiz. Any suggestions?